# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Delete
     @ID nvarchar(64),
     @value int = 0 output
AS
BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM A where Ap = @ID))
    BEGIN
        set @value = 1
    END
    ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B where Bp = @ID))
    BEGIN
        set @value = 2
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * 
        from Table_D
    END
END

RETURN @value
```

Problem is that when I execute it, this does not return any value

Comment: You have changed this question - Is the problem you are getting no RETURN VALUE (from the return) or no RESULTS SET (from the select)?

Comment: @SamMakin return is working but i want that if my first two condition are false then in my last condition they show me all data from my Table_D.

Comment: @user3441151: how are calling this stored procedure? where do you want to store the data from `Table_D`?

Comment: Do not use `RETURN` for returning data unless your client framework supports nothing else -- it's not useful as a general approach as it only supports a single `INT`. You can use either the result set or an output parameter -- from your question it's not clear what you are going for. `RETURN` just about works for an error code, but even then it's usually more appropriate to use `RAISERROR`.

Comment: @SamMakin how i check in c#, the given result is value or not.

Comment: @SamMakin I want that in c# code if i recieve value(1 or 2) then it show me alert else bind data. is it possible?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I want that in c# code if i recieve value(1 or 2) then it show me alert else bind data. is it possible?

Comment: @user3441151: I may have gone a little overboard in my answer covering all possible cases. Let me know if you need something less general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of returning status information from a stored procedure to an application. Each has its pros and cons; no single technique can definitely be said to be the right one in all circumstances. Even so, I'll start off with:

### TL;DR: recommendation

Use `RAISERROR` if your stored procedure runs into trouble and cannot return the data it normally returns. Use `OUTPUT` parameters for information the client isn't free to ignore, but which isn't logically part of your result. Use the return value if you have an informational status code that the client is free to ignore. Use additional result sets only if you know what you're doing.

### RAISERROR

If your stored procedure encounters an error and can't return any data, you can use `RAISERROR` to terminate execution and cause an exception to be raised on the client side.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Delete]
     @ID nvarchar(64)
AS BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM A where Ap = @ID))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Wrong. Try again.', 11, 1);
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B where Bp = @ID))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Wrong in a different way. Try again.', 11, 2);
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * 
        from Table_D
    END
END
```

The second parameter (severity) must be set to at least 11 to make the error propagate as an exception, otherwise it's just an informational message. Those can be captured too, but that's out of the scope of this answer. The third parameter (state) can be whatever you like and could be used to pass the code of the error, if you need to localize it, for example. User-generated message always have SQL error code 50000, so that can't be used to distinguish different errors, and parsing the message is brittle.

The C# code to process the result:

```cs
try {
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            ...
        }
    }
} catch (SqlException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Database error executing [Delete] (code {0}): {1}", e.State, e.Message
    );
}
```

This is a natural fit for errors because the code to actually process the data stays what it is, and you can handle the exception at the right location (rather than propagating a status code everywhere). But this method is not appropriate if the stored procedure is *expected* to return a status that is informational and not an error, as you would be catching exceptions all the time even though nothing's wrong.

### Output parameter

A stored procedure can set parameter values as well as receive them, by declaring them `OUTPUT`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Delete]
     @ID nvarchar(64),
     @StatusCode INT OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM A where Ap = @ID))
    BEGIN
        SET @StatusCode = 1;
    END
    ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B where Bp = @ID))
    BEGIN
        SET @StatusCode = 2;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @StatusCode = 0;
        select * 
        from Table_D
    END
END
```

From C#, this is captured in a parameter marked as an output parameter:

```cs
SqlParameter statusCodeParameter = command.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter {
        ParameterName = "@StatusCode",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
    }
);
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    int statusCode = (int) statusCodeParameter.Value;
    if (statusCode != 0) {
        // show alert
        return;
    }
    while (reader.Read()) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

The benefits here are that the client cannot forget to declare the parameter (it must be supplied), you're not restricted to a single `INT`, and you can use the value of the parameter to decide what you want to do with the resul set. Returning structured data is cumbersome this way (lots of `OUTPUT` parameters), but you could capture this in a single `XML` parameter.

### Return value

Every stored procedure has a return value, which is a single `INT`. If you don't explicitly set it using `RETURN`, it stays at 0.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Delete]
     @ID nvarchar(64)
AS BEGIN
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM A where Ap = @ID))
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B where Bp = @ID))
    BEGIN
        RETURN 2
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select * 
        from Table_D
    END
END
```

From C#, the return value has to be captured in a single special parameter marked as the return value:

```cs
SqlParameter returnValueParameter = command.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue }
);
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    // this could be empty
    while (reader.Read()) {
        ...
    }
}
int returnValue = (int) returnValueParameter.Value;
```

It's important to note that the return value will not be available until you've processed all other result sets that the stored procedure generates (if any), so if you're using it for a status code that indicates there are no rows, you must still process the empty result set first before you have the status code. You cannot return anything other than an `INT`. Frameworks/OR mappers often have no support for the return value. Finally, note that the client is not required to do anything with the return value, so you have to carefully document its intended use.

### Result set

The stored procedure can simply return what it wants as the result set, just like it's returning the other data. A stored procedure is allowed to return multiple result sets, so even if your status is logically separate from the other data, you can return it as a row.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [Delete]
     @ID nvarchar(64)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @StatusCode INT = 0;
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM A where Ap = @ID))
    BEGIN
        SET @StatusCode = 1;
    END
    ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B where Bp = @ID))
    BEGIN
        SET @StatusCode = 2;
    END

    SELECT @StatusCode AS StatusCode;

    IF @StatusCode = 0
    BEGIN
        select * 
        from Table_D
    END
END
```

To process this with C#, we need `SqlDataReader.NextResult`:

```cs
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    if (!reader.Read()) throw new MyException("Expected result from stored procedure.");
    statusCode = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("StatusCode"));
    if (statusCode != 0) {
        // show alert
        return;
    }
    reader.NextResult();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        // use the actual result set
    }
}
```

The main drawback here is that it's not intuitive for a stored procedure to return a variable number of result sets, and very few data frameworks/OR mappers support it, so you'll nearly always end up writing manual code like this. Returning multiple result sets is not really a good fit for returning a single piece of data like a status code, but it might be an alternative to returning structured data in an `XML` output parameter (especially if there's lots).

Comment: Nice answer +1 - I bet its lost on the OP though, who does not really know what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

The return seems to be out of  scope of the procedure. Try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Delete
    @ID nvarchar(64),
    @value int=0 output
AS
BEGIN

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM A where Ap=@ID))
    BEGIN
        set @value=1
    END

    ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B where Bp=@ID))
    BEGIN
        set @value=2
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
    set @value=5
    end --end if

    RETURN @value
end --end procedure
```

This is where using tabbing properly makes the code a lot more readable, and these problems more obvious

Comment: This actually makes no difference, thanks to a quirk of T-SQL. The entire body of the batch is part of the stored procedure -- you can leave out `BEGIN` and `END` and it would make no difference. This can easily come back to bite you if extra statements appear "after the end" -- there actually is no end.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the output parameter. Rather, use this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Delete
@ID nvarchar(64)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @value int
SET @value = 0

IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A where Ap=@ID))
BEGIN
set @value=1
END

ELSE IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B where Bp=@ID))
BEGIN
set @value=2
END

ELSE
BEGIN
set @value=5
end

Select @value as Value, * from Table_D
end
```

Comment: Sorry! Didn't even test it. :P I thought he was doing something wrong in the front end where he was getting the parameter back like  InOutParameter or something.

Comment: @SorrelVesper i want that intead of "set @value=5" i want to show all record from Table_D. Is that possible?

Comment: Your updated question doesnt make sense - you have left the original issue, while you have introduced another problem, in the select statement.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Select @value as Value, * from Table_D . I think that is what you mean, right? Or you could use two select statements and then in the front end, you will have to go like tbl[0] for first and tbl[1] for second datatable gotten from this query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the SP as the script below?

```
declare @pID as nvarchar(64)
declare @pValue as int

set @pID = 1 -- Your ID filter

exec Delete @pID, @pValue OUTPUT

select @pValue
```